# Show Send On Behalf in Outlook 2016 Preview Pane

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, exchange, microsoft-outlook-2016

I have a requirement to show the message "Shared Mailbox Name sent on behalf of User Name" in the preview pane of Outlook 2016. Right now if an email is sent on behalf of a shared mailbox by a user, the preview pane will just show the shared mailbox name in the preview pane. I'd like it to show the full "sent on behalf of" info without having to click on the email to see that info in the reading pane. Is this possible?

[image: IMG:]

Answer (score 0):

As I know, I'm afraid that it is by design and we could not make changes to it. If you would still like the feature you mentioned, it is suggested to submit your feedback via Outlook UserVoice.